# My questionnaire has more than two multiple response questions. Can I make one data set for all or separate data set needs to be created for each?

Tags: spss

I have collected 100 data for my survey using google form. Now I would like analyze in the SPSS. During data entry in the SPSS I see that there are 4 multiple response questions and I also have yes/no answer [questionaire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U4vB.jpg). As each question is having multiple variable I can not fit all the data in one data set. How can I solve this problem. Do I need to create separate data set for each multiple response questions?

I was trying add all type of answers in one record/row but due to multiple response answer I could not make one row record for all answers.

Comment: I don't see any reason to separate this into different data sets. Work with `Data -> Define multiple response sets` and find a tutorial like [this one](https://libguides.library.kent.edu/SPSS/Multiple-Response-Sets), you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Thank you. As I have very little knowledge on it- for an example I have total 5 questions, out of those, 4 questions are yes/no type and one is a multiple selection type that has 6 options. So now should I create total 4+6 =10 variables? How will I name the fifth question as it was 6 variables? 

You response is always appreciated.

Comment: OK so what you need is a way to turn your multiple response data from one variable to N variables according to number of possible answers. Please edit your post to add a bit of sample data from your dataset, and we can help you write the syntax to do this.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the sample questionnaire I added. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U4vB.jpg

Comment: Rather than how the questionnaire looks, the point is to see how the data looks in spss. Please edit your post and add some sample data in a table.

Comment: I am still not there. I will update soon. I am facing another issue that I am using almost same questionnaire for Male and Female. But the female questionnaire has 2 different questions and all other questions are common for male and female. Can I use same data set for male and female in that case?

Comment: Look at your export file (whatever format it is in), you should be able to see.